# Apache error on SuSE : Invalid command RewriteEngine, perhaps misspelled

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, sles

Webserver: Apache 2.4 on SuSE 12, multiple vhosts

4 vhosts (2 ssl, 2 http) have `RewriteEngine on` and some simple rewrite rules.

mod_rewrite is available and active (checked with `a2enmod -l`)

Problem: if I issued a `httpd -t` to check the syntax, I received for the two http vhosts a warning:

```
AH00526: Syntax error Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled
or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

After having added `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` ... `</IfModule>` lines around the rewrite blocks the warning disappeared.

Question: Why is there no warning with respect to the two ssl vhosts, which also have the RewriteEngine on, but no enclosing IfModule lines?

Comment: Do the two SSL vhosts work correctly on the appropriate port?

Comment: In what order are the various config files loaded? If the http host configs are loaded before the mod_rewrite module, but the ssl hosts are loaded after, that would eplain it.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment this line in your apache config, or add it if it doesn't exist:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Restart apache.

Comment: What difference would this make? According to "a2enmod -l" this module is already loaded. The line you proposed is also not set in the ssh-vhosts, and httpd -t does not complain about them...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10144634/1028276